# Capistrano and Corkscrew PATH error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, capistrano, gitlab

I'm trying to deploy my Rails application with Capistrano but when it comes to "git ls-remote" i get the following error:

```
$ /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@git.<server>:<project>.git
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: corkscrew: not found
DEBUG [a5205e2a]    ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
DEBUG [a5205e2a]    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I try to run the command on the server there is no problem. I've also got a deploy ssh key for the "deployer" user in gitlab.

Corkscrew is located under ~/bin/corkscrew and is added to the PATH variable.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/deployer/.rbenv/shims:/home/deployer/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/deployer/bin

$ corkscrew
corkscrew 2.0 (agroman@agroman.net)

usage: corkscrew <proxyhost> <proxyport> <desthost> <destport> [authfile]

$ which corkscrew
~/bin/corkscrew
```

Update:

Here is my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand corkscrew <server> 8088 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

While the ~/.ssh/proxyauth file contains the credentials of the proxy user.

If you need additional information please let me know.

Comment: Why are you running the first line with `/usr/bin/env`? Also, what does your `~/.ssh/config` entry for the server in question look like?

Comment: The first line is an exact copy of what Capistrano is running. I've added the .shh/config file to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `ssh` can't find the `corkscrew` executable. I double-checked my local `~/.ssh/config` file, and I use the full path to the `corkscrew` executable in there:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew <server> 8088 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

(Since I'm on OS X and have installed `corkscrew` through Homebrew, it's located in `/usr/local/bin`.)

Can you try to update your `~/.ssh/config` to include the full path to the `corkscrew` executable? Something like this (I don't know whether the `~` will work, you might have to use the full path if it doesn't):

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand ~/bin/corkscrew <server> 8088 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tested both:

 ~/bin/corkscrew <server> 8088 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth

and

 /home/deployer/bin/corkscrew <server> 8088 %h %p /home/deployer/.ssh/proxyauth

Both work fine but just to be sure i will use the second one.